# Disabling user interaction not working in SVProgressHUD on iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, svprogresshud

I've just downloaded SVProgressHUD and incorporated it into my project as explained in the github documentation page, but even if I wrote out `[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];`, it's not different from the default mask type, and when I tapped the screen while the cursor was revolving I got my app crashed - meaning I wasn't able to disable the user interaction feature since my app crashes before showing all of the table view cells there.

And note that `clear` or `black` mask type didn't work, either.

So how can I successfully disable the user interaction? And which file of the `AppDelegate.m`'s `applicationDidFinishWithLaunchingOptions:` and `FirstViewController.`'s `viewDidLoad:` should I write the above code?

I use the latest version of the `SVProgressHUD` and use Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1. I also use ARC. Am I missing something?

#### [Update]

This was a bug issue and it has been resolved in the current version. Check it out on the [Github page](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/issues/253) for the further info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything. iOS 7 doesn't seem to respect the mask type, so user interaction is never disabled. I think it's a bug with SVProgressHUD rather than anything else. Bit frustrating really.

Comment: Thanks. Just found the same issue reported on [Github](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/issues/253) in iOS 7.1/Xcode 5.1. Hope it gets fixed...

Comment: can you check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642980/ios-svprogresshud-doesnt-dismiss-when-user-moves-from-one-screen-to-another-in

Answer (score 12):

This is very late to answer but just in case it can help someone because I was stuck with this issue for a while today. If you are using latest classes from github you won't face any issue but if you are using old classes then Replace below method from SVProgressHUD.m as below

```
+ (void)showWithStatus:(NSString *)status 
  {   
     [self setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
     [self showProgress:SVProgressHUDUndefinedProgress status:status];
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

I am using `SVProgressHUD` with swift and iOS 10.2 . Just setting mask type

**In AppDelegate**

`SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.black)` works.

and every time you write

`SVProgressHUD.show()`

it will show the mask and userInteraction is managed by it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily by doing some changes in `SVProgressHUD` class:
just put
   `[self.window setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` in the last of `showprogress with status` and put `[self.window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` in `dismiss` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C (AppDelegate.m)**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //add this line
    [SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType: SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
}
```