# SVProgressHUD user interaction Disable not working on Xcode 11 and iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13, user-interaction, svprogresshud

Don't duplicate the question! I have checked many answers and try many solutions but nothing is woking.

I have newly created project on `Xcode 11`, and add `SVProgressHUD` on it and showing `HUD` it was working fine, but background component `user interaction` doesn't disable on it. Currently I have implemented below code:

```
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultStyle:SVProgressHUDStyleLight];
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultAnimationType:SVProgressHUDAnimationTypeFlat];
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Message"] ;
```

I use the latest version of the `SVProgressHUD` and use `Xcode 11` and `iOS 13`. `MaskType` not working, how can I disable the `user interaction`?

Edit:

- It was working fine on projects that Xcode 10 or below version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling user interaction not working in SVProgressHUD on iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396175/disabling-user-interaction-not-working-in-svprogresshud-on-ios-app)

Comment: @SeanLintern I have checked this but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, this issue occurs due to `SceneDelegate` files.

I have set old behaviour back to the app:

1. Delete the "**Application Scene Manifest**" entry from the Info.plist
2. Delete the "**UISceneSession lifecycle**" methods from `AppDelegate.m`
3. Delete the "**SceneDelegate.h and SceneDelegate.m**" files from project.
4. Add the window property back to the `AppDelegate` (ex. `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;`)

After that I have try to run with below code and it's working fine on app.

```
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultStyle:SVProgressHUDStyleLight];
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultAnimationType:SVProgressHUDAnimationTypeFlat];
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Message"] ;
```